# undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass when adding boolean values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

In the console of my application I get "undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass" when attempting to set a Boolean to true or false.

For instance if I do

```
Man.create(guy: true) # or 
Man.create(:guy => true) # etc
```

I have not worked on this application for several months and I believe everything was working fine before I stopped work on it. I am pretty new to Ruby and have limited programming knowledge so any help is much appreciated. creating rows and providing only string or integer values works fine. I am using an SQLite3 database if that matters.

guy is a Boolean

```
class AddMan < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :men do |t|
      t.boolean :guy
      t.boolean :girl
      t.boolean :dude
      t.boolean :lady
      t.boolean :albert

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Man < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :guys
    has_many :girls
end
```

Comment: Without any further information it's impossible to help. What's the `guy` property? What's the model look like? Any callbacks? Etc.

Comment: edited for clarification

Comment: can you post your View's code

Comment: This happens in the console. I don't think the view is relevant.

Comment: I made a new test application and tried this and it worked fine. I will run a file compare between the two directories and report if I see a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
has_many :guys
has_many :girls
```

assumes, by Rails convention, the presence of Integer columns `:guy_id` and `girl_id`, which should be foreign keys into the `guys` and `girls` tables, respectively. These are not present in your schema, so I assume that's the root cause of the error you're seeing.

In general, try avoiding column names that may be in conflict with other models (I assume you have models named `Guy` and `Girl`. Try renaming your boolean columns to something like `is_guy` and `is_girl`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I knew it had to be something simple but it was getting frustrating.

Comment: The funny part about this issue was that the Booleans already had values of true and false in them. It was after I assigned them that I created more models with bad names and made this issue. But it did not show up until I wanted to change some of the Booleans. Again, Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

From your `Man` Model I assumes that you have `guys` and `girls` different tables. And from your console it seems that you want to assign value to `Man` table's `guy` attribute. 
If this is the case then you can assign value to your `Man` table's `guy` attribute like

```
man = Man.new
man.guy = true
```